# Duda conceptos basicos Ruby - variables de instancia

Tags: ruby

Tengo una duda acerca del siguiente codigo, lo resolvi y esta correcto, pero no entiendo una parte, es acerca de la variable @energia`

```
    module Pepo
  @energia = 1000

  def self.energia
    @energia
  end

  def self.volar_en_circulos!
    if @energia>1100
    @energia -= 15
    else
    @energia -= 5
      
    end
  end

  def self.comer_alpiste!(gramos)
   @energia += gramos /2
  end  

  

  def self.hacer_lo_que_quiera!
   self.comer_alpiste!(120)
  end
end
```

Como ven tengo la variable `@energia` inicializada con 1000 y dentro del metodo `volar_en_circulos!` solo colocando @energia la puedo acceder. Mi pregunta es... por que si borro

```
def self.energia
    @energia
  end
```

apesar de que arriba tengo declarada la variable @energia ya no puedo accederla desde `volar_en_circulos!`si igualmente la accedo desde un metodo de la clase.

Comment: [Probé lo que mencionas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT4Vj.png) y no me dió problemas, efectivamente está restando 5 cada vez que ejecuto el método. ¿a que te refieres que ya no puedes accederla? ¿te sale algún error en particular? ¿de qué forma estás llamando el método?

Comment: borraste el metodo self.energia? y los otros metodos funcionan?

Comment: ...supongo no viste el pantallazo que compartí contigo, pero si, agregué solo el método `volar_en_circulos!` y `@energia = 1000`.

Answer (score 0):

Porque no has dado permisos para leer la variable con:

```
attr_reader :energia
```

Quedaría así:

```
module Pepo
  attr_reader :energia

  @energia = 1000

  ...
end
```

Antes podías leerla porque tenías el método volar_en_circulos! en la devolvía.

De todas maneras es un poco raro lo que intentas hacer, ya que @energia es una variable de instancia, y se supone que las variables de instancia se usan en Clases.  Las puedes usar en módulo para hacer Mixin, es decir, incluir el módulo en una clase.  En ese caso, no podrías acceder a la variable como un atributo del módulo (MiModulo.energia), sino como un atributo del objeto instanciado.

Está un poco raro.